# Hibernate connection failed

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, maven

I wannted to connect with maven hibernate to my webservice project to connect databese. I've watched a video on yt and it was working but in my project won't but i do it the same way as this guy.

Its my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MyWebService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is application property file

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/springboot
server.port=9090
menagement.security.enabled=false

#Hibernate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:9090/springboot
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#Jpa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Here is a console log

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-05-26 16:21:22.313  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] com.webservice.Application               : Starting Application on DESKTOP-7IMDU22 with PID 17324 (C:\Users\Daniel\eclipse-workspace\MyWebService\target\classes started by Daniel in C:\Users\Daniel\eclipse-workspace\MyWebService)
2020-05-26 16:21:22.318  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] com.webservice.Application               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-26 16:21:22.372  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-05-26 16:21:22.373  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-05-26 16:21:23.366  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-05-26 16:21:23.392  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-26 16:21:24.432  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2020-05-26 16:21:24.443  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-26 16:21:24.443  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-26 16:21:24.564  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/springboot]    : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-26 16:21:24.565  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2192 ms
2020-05-26 16:21:24.928  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-26 16:21:24.982  INFO 17324 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-26 16:21:25.007  WARN 17324 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-05-26 16:21:25.059  INFO 17324 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-26 16:21:25.263  INFO 17324 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-26 16:21:25.404  INFO 17324 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-26 16:21:30.605 ERROR 17324 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    ... 36 common frames omitted

2020-05-26 16:21:30.607  WARN 17324 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2020-05-26 16:21:30.624  INFO 17324 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2020-05-26 16:21:31.306  INFO 17324 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-26 16:21:36.334 ERROR 17324 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:43) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:60) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:67) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:333) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:400) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:243) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    ... 35 common frames omitted

2020-05-26 16:21:36.336  WARN 17324 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
2020-05-26 16:21:36.336 ERROR 17324 --- [         task-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2020-05-26 16:21:36.406  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-05-26 16:21:36.412  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-05-26 16:21:36.470  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path '/springboot'
2020-05-26 16:21:36.472  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-05-26 16:21:36.473  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-05-26 16:21:36.483  INFO 17324 --- [  restartedMain] com.webservice.Application               : Started Application in 14.586 seconds (JVM running for 15.174)
```

I can't understand what happend.

Please be forgiving and thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure you set the configuration parameter `spring.datasource.url` to the correct url your database is reachable? `jdbc:mysql://localhost:9090/springboot` looks like it is just the url your application webserver and not to wherever you are running your database server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your MySQL database service is not running or the URL is incorrect. MySQL database service by default runs at port 3306,

Sample connection url,

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<database-schema>?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Here's how you can start the locally installed MySQL database service.

[image]

To granting privileges to the user, run the below queries,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I've chandged a port but now i have something like this

Comment: I've post it in answer

Comment: @DanielAvoyan you need to grant privileges for the user root. See my updated answer. And since you are a new user, note that you cannot add exception as an answer. Update the current question with the latest issue or start a new question thread. :)

Comment: Where i should write it ?

Comment: @DanielAvoyan you can use the MySQL workbench and log in as root or using MySQL command line client

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin and entered that two lines and nothing happend. It returned 0.

Comment: It says that i have not choose any db

Comment: you need to add one more line, `USE <database-schema-name>`. For example `USE my-employees`. What is the url you are trying to connet to db from application

Comment: Again not working `USE springboot;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and says that i have not choose db. The url is `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot`

Comment: my app still throws `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 0):

Try another user and password because the root user in MySQL has no password, or try to alter the root user and give it a password.

```
Option A:
CREATE DATABASE springboot;
CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';
GRANT ALL ON springboot.* TO 'admin'@'%';

Option B:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Comment: It works thank you, but it crated 2 tables one is my user and one is "hibernate sequence" what is that

Comment: It's a table generated by hibernate for generating the primary keys

Comment: can i somehow disable it?

Comment: it throws Field 'id' doesn't have a default value